# How to hide certain texts retrieved from Strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have an English teaching app where the users are given some sentences with their Turkish equivalents. I retrieve the data from Strings.xml as follows:

```xml
<.b>Possession (Aitlik)</b>\n\nhave
        (sahip olmak)\npossess (sahip olmak)\nown (sahip olmak)\nbelong (ait olmak)\nconsist (-den meydana gelmek)\nlack (eksik olmak)\ninvolve
        (içermek)\n\n<.b>Emotions (Duygular)</b>\n\nlike (sevmek)\ndislike (sevmemek)\nprefer (tercih etmek)\nappreciate (takdir etmek)\nneed
        (ihtiyacı olmak)\nwish (istemek, dilemek)\nhope (ummak)\nvalue (değer vermek)\nadore (hayran olmak)\nfear (korkmak)\nsurprise (şaşırtmak)\nenvy
        (kıskanmak)\nhate (nefret etmek)\nlove (sevmek)\n\n
    ...
```

If the user wishes, I'd like to hide the translations of the words. Is there a way to do it? So far, I tried separating the example sentences from their translations and hiding the translations from the code:

```xml
<string name=header_one>"<.b>Possession</b>"</string>
<string name=header_one_translation>"<.b>Aitlik</b>"</string>
```

```kotlin
binding.hideTranslationsButton.setOnClickListener {
            binding.headerOneTranslation.isGone = true
            binding.translationOne.isGone = true
            binding.translationTwo.isGone = true
            binding.translationThree.isGone = true
            binding.translationFour.isGone = true
            binding.translationFive.isGone = true
            binding.translationSix.isGone = true
            ...
        }
```

but it took too much time and it feels like my code has gotten messier considering I have 50 other grammar topics like this (I put dots intentionally --> <.b>).

Comment: Couldn't you group all translations in one layout and hide the whole layout instead of hiding all elements themself?

Comment: It'd be great but I have separate sentences within separate layouts so I cannot merge them in a single layout.

Comment: Probably you can use a regex like `(\(.*\)) *(.*)` and use `match.groups(1)` (English) and `match.group(2)` (Turkish)

Comment: @Amin I just implemented the method you said and it works perfectly now thanks! I'd like to give you an upvote so could you write it to the answers section, please?

Comment: Yeah of course, actually I'm on my phone so I decided put a comment, but will write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
(\(.*\)) *(.*)
```

It simply says there is a group (first parenthesis pair - group 1) inside that we expect
a opening parenthesis `\(`

then anything except linebreak `.` with any count `*` (probably `+` is even better instead of `*` so it can skip empty items)

then we expect a closing parentheses `\)`

then there might be some spaces which we don't care about  `*`

and then another group (group 2) which is whatever with any count `.*` (again, `+` seems more suitable)

So you can use something like

```
"(\(.+\)) *(.+)".toRegex().matches(getString(R.string.blah_blah)).forEach{
    val en = it.groups[1]
    val tr = it.groups[2]
}
```

Comment: Also if your string is huge, I suggest you to move it to a database (e.g. parse it in a small app on your machine, write by java or kotlin or whatever, which parse the data and put it into a SQLite database and then ship the data using it) as regex time complexity is `O(n^2)` and if your data is huge, probably your app's performance might suffer from it

Answer (score 0):

use recycleview and handle hide text in adapter of recycleview

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think about reordering your layouts. 
Dunno what your structure is.

```
<LinearLayout id=root>
   <LinearLayout id=english>
       <LinearLayout id=sentence1/>
       <LinearLayout id=sentence2/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout id=turkish>
       <LinearLayout id=translate1/>
       <LinearLayout id=translate2/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and now you hide the turkish layout.